# Control Order of SQL Scripts in Install Shield

Tags: installshield, installshield-2008

How do you control the order to run SQL scripts in Install Shield 2008? I moved the one I want to run first on the script list, but it seems to not be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a InstallScript installer, they are processed in the order their respective components are processed. To override this, you must right click on SQL Scripts and turn on batch mode.